# StateMachine transitions based on model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine

I'm using [finite machine](https://github.com/piotrmurach/finite_machine) to handle the state of `Project`s. Each project belongs to a `Category` and each category has many `Step`s. 
Now I'd like to define in my `ProjectStateMachine` the `next` event which transits a project to the next steps according to its current state and category of belonging.

For instance, let's assume I have the "`new lab`" project (in the `submitted` state) associated with the `equipment` category. The `equipment` category has `['submitted', 'started', 'completed']` steps.

When the `next` event happens for the `new lab` project, its state becomes `started` and then when the `next` event happens again, the project goes in the `completed` state.

Is there a way to achieve so?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with that specific gem (more on that later), but I would think you could do something like:

```
events {
  self.category.steps.each_cons(2) do |set|
    event :next, set[0].to_sym => set[1].to_sym
  end
}
```

But with that said, the gem you referenced has not been updated in over a year. I'd recommend going with something more recent such as [this](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord) (if you're using ActiveRecord which is based upon the [state-machines gem](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines#static--dynamic-definitions)). This last link takes you to a specific section on dynamic definitions, which will certainly give you what you want.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I don't plan to change the gen since the app already uses that for many models.